# Can I use azure event grid domain to send events to multiple topics?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I have done following experiment and it works:

- Configured the azure event grid domain with 2 topics.
- Published an event to the domain with topic 1 info in it.
- The event is successfully delivered to topic 1 (and not topic 2) as expected.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to send an event to the domain so that it can be delivered to multiple topics (in the above case topic 1 and topic 2)?
2. If it is possible, how do I go about it?
3. If it is not possible today, will this be available later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to send an event to the domain so that it can be delivered to multiple topics (in the above case topic 1 and topic 2)?

This is not strictly possible today. Generally, the broadcasting scenario as you have described is solved by creating multiple subscriptions on the *same* topic. The primary reason for publishing to different topics within a Domain is for authorization purposes.

If you want a different group of users to be able to subscribe to events from topic 1 vs. topic 2, then breaking into two topics makes sense. If the same users can have access to the same set of events, then they can usually be granted access to the same topic.

If you don't want all events flowing to each endpoint, this is where filters become applicable.

> If it is possible, how do I go about it?

If you want the same event to be available on two different topics, you will have to publish the event twice to the Domain, once for each topic.

A second option, depending on your use case is the availability of "firehose" style event subscriptions. Each Domain can also support a limited set of Event Subscriptions at the Domain scope (subscribe to all events in the Domain). This doesn't publish to both topics, but could be an alternative architecture depending on your need.

> If it is not possible today, will this be available later?

TBD. Do you have a use-case in mind that is blocked?

Comment: No blocking issue at this time. Just trying to see if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a difference between the Domain Topics and Custom Topics. The Domain Topics are loosely decoupled to the subscribers and they are creating dynamically based on the subscriber interest.

In other words, if there is no interest (no subscription) for that domain topic, the domain topic doesn't exist in the Event Domain and the event message published for that domain topic will forward it to the domain subscriber (if there is a domain subscription).

In your case, you have created two subscriptions on the event domain topic1 and topic2. If these subscriptions have been created first time for that topics, then the domain will create automatically these topics (topic1, topic2) in the event domain resource.

The AEG Event Domain preview supports to send an array of the events to the event domain topics. The following screen snippet shows an example events using a default input schema (such as EventGridSchema):

```
[
 {
   "topic": "topic1",
   "id": "12345",
   "subject": "/myapp/vehicles/motorcycles",
   "eventType": "recordInserted",
   "eventTime": "2019-02-05T16:57:16.5734282Z",
   "data": {
     "make": "Ducati",
     "model": "Monster"
     }
 },
 {
   "topic": "topic2",
   "id": "67890",
   "subject": "/myapp/vehicles/motorcycles",
   "eventType": "recordInserted",
   "eventTime": "2019-02-05T16:57:16.5734282Z",
   "data": {
     "make": "Ducati",
     "model": "Monster"
     }
 }
]
```

As you can see, the above each event (in this EventGridSchema) is mapping an interest source to the domain topic. The special case is when we used a CustomInputSchema, where this mapping can be customized (such as default value and/or sourceField).

The answer for your question about the "topic broadcasting" in the AEG Pub/Sub Model is NO. **The AEG model supports only subscribing to one topic**. It will be nice to subscribe for multiple topics within the event domain, for instance using an advanced filtering with the key = topic, but it doesn't work.

**Subscribing to Event Domain for Fan-Out pattern:**

The special case can be a subscribing for event domain and using an advanced filtering, see the following an example:

```
 "advancedFilters": [
      {
        "values": [
          "topics/topic1",
          "topics/topic2"
        ],
        "operatorType": "StringEndsWith",
        "key": "topic"
      }
```

Based on the above "workaround" you can create multiple Fan-Out (broadcasting) groups within the event domain. The limit for domain scope event subscriptions is 50 during this public preview.

The Event Domains is a great feature in the AEG eventing model, for instance, there is a built-in an event aggregation (Fan-In pattern) on the domain level topic. If the interest source event has unknown domain topic (there is no subscription), the event can be captured by domain subscriber.

Comment: In fan-out model domain subscription above, will the event (sent to domain) get sent to unknown domain topics 1 and 2? If so, what good is it to send the event to these non-subscribed topics because event does not go anywhere from those topics? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Subscribing to the Event Domain (not to the domain topic) will capture all events with no "registered" domain topics (no subscriptions for that domain topics). This is an unique case in the AEG model because the others subscribing is done with a topic.

Comment: I would like to correct the following: based on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-domains#subscribing-to-topics, the document stated that "An event subscription on an event domain will receive all events sent to the domain regardless of the topic the events are sent to." Anyway, the point of my workaround stayed the same, that the event domain subscription is receiving all events from the domain topics and based on the advanced filtering we can handled a Fan-out (broadcasting) groups.